# Adding the Legend title using GetLegendGraphic request in GeoServer to Leaflet

Tags: geoserver, sld

I am trying to load the dynamic legend for GeoServer using `GetLegendGraphic` request. My `GetLegendGraphic` URL is something like this,

```
http://localhost/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.1.0&FORMAT=image/png&LAYER=demo:risk&style=loss_fl:
```

I generated the style file using QGIS. My `sld` file is something like this;

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1.0" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>Jamoats_risk</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>Jamoats_risk</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>0 </se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>0 </se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>aal_fl_peop</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>aal_fl_peop</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>0.06200000000000017</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#1a9641</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>0.062 </se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>0.062 </se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                <ogc:PropertyName>aal_fl_peop</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>0.06200000000000017</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>aal_fl_peop</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>0.17999999999999999</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#a6d96a</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>0.18 </se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>0.18 </se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                <ogc:PropertyName>aal_fl_peop</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>0.17999999999999999</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>aal_fl_peop</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>0.57600000000000018</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ffffc0</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>0.576 </se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>0.576 </se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                <ogc:PropertyName>aal_fl_peop</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>0.57600000000000018</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>aal_fl_peop</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>1.54800000000000071</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#fdae61</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>1.548 </se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>1.548 </se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                <ogc:PropertyName>aal_fl_peop</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>1.54800000000000071</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>aal_fl_peop</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>22.48000000000000043</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#d7191c</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

The above style file is able to produce the legend like following,

[image]

But what I want is, I want to add the title as `Average Annual losses (Hectares)` just above the legend items. Is there any possible way to do so?

I already tried to add the `<Title>Average Annual losses (Hectares)</Title>` under `<UserStyle>` tag. But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Legend always returns the `Title` tag as the layer title. I think you may update your `se:Title` tag and replace the value `0` with your custom title. For your case, you can write,

```
<se:Title>Average Annual losses (Hectares)</se:Title>
```

instade of,

```
<se:Title>0 </se:Title>
```

Comment: I don't think this solves it - this will just change the swatch title for 0 as opposed to adding in a title above it.